# Flex box: Fill remaining space but justify content center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve a layout looking like the following:

[image: flex box goal]

In other words, the last item takes up the "remaining space" in  away that the other items are centered *as if* item 3 is **equally sized** to item 1 and 2. The closest I can get to this is this layout:

[image]

I've also tried setting `height: 100%` on the last item, which of course doesn't work since that pushes item 1 and 2 to the top. Here's the snippet that I don't know how to finish:

```css
/* Default values are skipped */
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
   background: red;
}

.item-fill {
   background: yellow;
   /* What should go in here? */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  First item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  Second item
  </div>
    <div class="item-fill">
  Third item which should fill up the rest of the parent space without pushing the first and second item upwards
  </div>
</div>
```

It might be that this cannot be solved with flex-box alone and needs hack, but I would be thankful to whomever can come up with the most simple solution.

Thank you.

Comment: It's fairly easy to do using a pseudo element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add a pseudo element that has a value of `flex-grow: 1;` (before the other items in your container) and set the same flex-grow value to `.item-fill`.

The pseudo-element (`.container:before` here), will fill the top part of the container as much as it can and the other item with a `flex-grow` value will fill the rest. The two other items will be as small as their content.

```css
/* Default values are skipped */

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container:before {
    content: "";
}

.container:before,
.item-fill {
    flex: 1;
}

.item {
   background: red;
}

.item-fill {
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  First item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  Second item
  </div>
    <div class="item-fill">
  Third item which should fill up the rest of the parent space without pushing the first and second item upwards
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What a nice solution, and well explained (in your edit). Thank you!

Comment: @Karamell Glad I could help :). There are other solutions without using a pseudo-element (by declaring a specific `flex-grow` value such as `flex: 1 0 50%;` for example or by playing with margins) but I find this one easier to understand and to manipulate. @kukkuz, thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try with `flex-grow` for your `item-fill` class.

The `flex-grow` property specifies how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item {
    background: red;
}

.item-fill {
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        First item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Second item
    </div>
    <div class="item-fill">
        Third item which should fill up the rest of the screen space without pushing the first and second item upwards
    </div>
</div>
```